# Angular 2 AOT compilation requires component name

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

I have an issue with AOT compilation. When I run a build task it asks me for some new component name. It will be an issue for CI. Here is an [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsAv7.png).

My **tsconfig.json** file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "removeComments": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": ".",
    "entryModule": "src/app/app.module#AppModule"
  }
}
```

Could someone please advise how to avoid this name input?`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it wasn't an issue! Be careful because there is a package with name "ngc" in npm so it has the same name as Angular Compiler CLI.

Comment: Yep. If you accidentally run `npm install ngc`, you'll get this alternative package binary instead of the angular compiler binary you want. This package is an unofficial component generator that asks for Name: to create a new component skeleton.